# How to generate a query string in a view from a scope object?

Tags: angularjs

in my view I've got a scope object which contains the params of my query.
What is the easiest way to generate a href attribute using it in a link in my view?

```
$scope.search_params // => { q: "test", order: "asc", filter: "price" }

// in my view I want to generate a link like this.
<a href="/search?q=test&order=asc&filter=price">...</a>
```

thanks.

Comment: Why not have method in the scope for that ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem : I thought that there were an equivalent of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ in angularjs ?

Comment: Nope ! Also, don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent()` s needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ng-href directive :

```
<a ng-href="/search?q={{ search_params.q }}&order={{ search_params.order }}&filter={{ search_params.filter }}">...</a>
```

If you want to customise your URL (when for example parameters are missing), you should create a custom function in your controller and refer it in the view.

Something like this :

```
$scope.myHref = function () {
    var res = '?';
    if (search_param.q) {
        res = res + 'q=' + search_param.q;
    }
    ...
}

<a ng-href="/search{{ myHref() }}">...</a>
```

I think that the first solution is much cleaner, and you should check the given URL after to check if it's null.

More info from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

Comment: OK but I don't want to add params in the URL which are null.